# How would I go about setting up a web hook listener on Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, localization, webhooks

**Goal:**
We have a Translation Management System project with a set of string translations, which can be exported as iOS, Android, and web formats. This can be done via its API, CLI, or manually with the UI. We need to integrate with our git-based repository, which lives in DevOps, so that when changes are made to the TMS translations, the code base is updated automatically (preferably a PR would be created with the changes).

**What I Have Tried:**
I am a mobile developer with little web hook experience, but it seems that they are the key to the solution. I can configure the web hook on the TMS side, but need to provide a URL with a listener. Going through the Azure DevOps service hooks settings and reading documentation extensively, I can't find any leads on a way to set up a custom listener to subscribe to another service's web hook, consume its payload, and trigger an action in DevOps.

I'm aware this may be limited by the capabilities of the TMS and DevOps, but how would this be tackled viewing it from a high level perspective? It doesn't seem like there's any built-in solution, so what would a custom solution entail? If something along the lines of what I'm looking for isn't possible, I would like to know that as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So that when changes are made to the TMS translations, the code base
>   is updated automatically (preferably a PR would be created with the
>   changes).

Sorry but as I know it's not supported scenario in Azure Devops Service.

1.The [service hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops) option in azure devops service is that when something(event) happens in Azure Devops Service, it runs task(action) on target service. But what you want is when something happens in external service, it runs task(action) in azure devops service. For now this behavior is not supported.

2.And different service in Service Hooks has different supported actions. Let's take Jenkins service(one service hooks) as example, see step5 in [trigger Jenkins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/jenkins?view=azure-devops#trigger-jenkins): Azure Devops can trigger Jenkins build.

As for [Web Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops)(another service hooks), it can't trigger actions like `the code base is updated automatically`. It just sends the Json representation.

So the scenario you want is not supported for now by Azure Devops Service.

**In addition:** Not sure about how your TMS works, but you can consider using [Azure Devops Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to trigger actions in Azure Devops Service. (These rest apis can be used to queue build, release or do git-related actions )

When changes are made to your TMS translations, you may call corresponding Azure Devops rest api to manage git repos in Azure Devops if your TMS supports this kind of behavior.

Hope all above resolves your puzzle why your scenario is not supported by Web Hooks in Azure Devops:)

Answer (score 0):

When you Authorize your GitHub repo through the devops settings, webhook will be automatically created on your repo with configurable hook events.